# Can I provide gcloud commands inside python in cloud function function

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to run gs command to copy data using python function in cloud function, is it possible to run a shell command inside the cloud function??.

Comment: No, because Cloud Functions is not an operating system. Cloud Functions provides a framework to execute well defined `functions` and not entire programs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation [Cloud Functions Execution Environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec):

> Cloud Functions run in a fully-managed, serverless environment where
>   Google handles infrastructure, operating systems, and runtime
>   environments completely on your behalf. Each Cloud Function runs in
>   its own isolated secure execution context, scales automatically, and
>   has a lifecycle independent from other functions.

These are the runtimes that cloud functions supports:

```
 Node.js 8, Node.js 10 (Beta), Python, Go 1.11, Go 1.13
```

Currently, it is not possible to run shell commands inside a Google Cloud Function.

However, assuming you would like to copy data to or from Cloud Storage, you can use [Cloud Storage Client Libraries for Python](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python)

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to see if it helps you achieve what you need? I haven't tried this myself so I can't be sure if it will work.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

Alternatively you can also use CloudRun to run [Docker image with gcloud sdk](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker) which could help you execute shell commands directly (rather than going via python).

Answer (score 0):

To interact with Google APIs from a Cloud function(Python runtime), shell command is not the ideal choice.
Google Cloud Platform has [Python libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) to interact with its service and I suggest to you them.

Sample Python code to list the objects in a GCS Bucket

```
from google.cloud import storage
bucket_name = "gcs-bucket-name"
gcs_client = storage.Client()
gcs_objects = gcs_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
  for obj in gcs_objects:
      print(obj.name)
```